# Django Models, ModelForm and validation

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

For the following model:

```
#models.py
class entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="/",blank=True)
    video_url = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True)
```

I want the model and corresponding ModelForm only be allowed *either* an `image` field or a `video_url` field, but **not** both.

How is this best accomplished? Do I need to validate on the model, the modelform, or both?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in your form you can use:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    m_image = cleaned_data.get('imagee')
    m_video_url = cleaned_data.get('video_url')

    if (m_image and m_video_url): 
        raise forms.ValidationError("Both video url and image sumbitted")

    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: @Tony i noticed that you just joined. If you feel that an answer is a good answer to your question consider marking it answer by pressing the check box so it stops showing up in the unanswered lists. Thanks! And glad it worked for you.